# CString join method?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to concatenate a list of MFC CString objects into a single CSV string. .NET has `String.Join` for this task. Is there an established way to do this in MFC/C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded to allow string concatenation. I'd suggest take a look at the documentation on MSDN:

[Basic CString Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx) has the following example:

```
CString s1 = _T("This ");        // Cascading concatenation
s1 += _T("is a ");
CString s2 = _T("test");
CString message = s1 + _T("big ") + s2;  
// Message contains "This is a big test".
```

If you want the strings to be comma-separated, just add the commas yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of CString objects invoking the AppendFormat method.

```
//  Initialize CStringList
CStringList cslist ;
cslist.AddTail( "yaba" ) ;
cslist.AddTail( "daba" ) ;
cslist.AddTail( "doo"  ) ;

//  Join
CString csv ;
for ( POSITION pos = cslist.GetHeadPosition() ; pos != NULL ; )
    csv.AppendFormat( ",%s" , cslist.GetNext( pos ) ) ;
csv.Delete( 0 ) ;  //  remove leading comma
```

Comment: Deleting the first char of a string has got to be the most expensive operation you can perform. Switch the comma around and delete the last char. Or just don't generate extra commas.